# keep an integer with SharedPreferences in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a one time page only first time this page will open and ı don't know how to keep this command. I think I should use SharedPreferences but couldn't do that. Please help me.

```
import 'package:eventer/landing/second.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  int index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: selecter(),
      ),
    );
  }

  selecter() {
    if (index == 0) {
      return FirstPage();
    } else { 
      () {
       return SecondPage();
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: did you install shared preference dependency?

Answer (score 2):

you can install sharedpreference dependency using pubspec.yaml file

```
    shared_preferences: ^0.5.4
```

then in your .dart file import package

```
  import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
```

you can store info  in sharedpreference like below

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setInt('index', index);
```

then you can retrieve value like this

```
var index_value = prefs.getInt('index');
```

then you can perform your condition accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin

Add dependencies to pubspec.yaml file.

```
shared_preferences: ^0.5.7+3
```

Import shared_preferences.dart

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

selecter() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int index = await prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0;
  if (index == 0) {
  await prefs.setInt('counter', 1;
    return FirstPage();
  } else {
    return SecondPage();
  }
}
```